# Can we redirect to in reduxSaga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I've a login page with HOC I pass component which must render be after successful login.

Here, if I check for isLoggedIn and redirect in render of sigin-in  for then I get error

> err: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

*saga.js*

```
           try{//call api
                //put login success
              <Redirect to="/app"/>        
            }
```

*index.js*

```
          const AuthProfile=requireAuth(App);

           In reactdom
             <Route render={(props)=><AuthProfile  {...props}/>} path="/app"/>  


          import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';  
          import { connect } from 'react-redux';  
          import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
          import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

          export default function (ComposedComponent) {  
            class Authenticate extends React.Component {


              componentDidMount() {
                console.log("12ra")
                this._checkAndRedirect();
              }

              componentDidUpdate() {
                this._checkAndRedirect();
              }

              _checkAndRedirect() {
                const { isLoggedIn, redirect } = this.props;

                if (!isLoggedIn) {
                  redirect();
                }
              }

              render() {
                console.log("28ra")
                return (
                  <div>
                    { this.props.isLoggedIn ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> : null }
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }

            const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
              return {
                isLoggedIn:state.signInReducer.isLoggedIn
              };
            };

            const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
              redirect: () => push('/')
            }, dispatch)

            //Authenticate.propTypes = propTypes

            return connect(
              mapStateToProps, 
              mapDispatchToProps
            )(Authenticate);
          }
```

Is HOC component correct or I'm missing on something?

Is it good practise to redirect in saga?

Can anyone please  lemme know how do I get to app component after success i'm stuck there please help thanks

**UPDATE**

*saga.js*

```
       yield put({type:LOGIN_SUCCESS,payload:data})
        yield put(push('/app'))
```

index.js

Ex for Page1,Page2 I need

```
        <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/"
      component={Page1}
      redirectTo="/login"
      authenticated={this.props.isLoggegIn}
    />

     <AuthRoute
      exact
      path="/"
      component={Page2}
      redirectTo="/login"
      authenticated={this.props.isLoggegIn}
    />
```

Answer (score 8):

Following is the way where you can navigate from saga:

**saga.js**

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
...
// after API call & validate user
yield put(push('/app'));
```

**index.js**

```
 <Route strict exact path='/app' component={App}>
 <AuthRoute
          exact
          path="/"
          component={Yourcomponent}
          redirectTo="/login"
          authenticated={hasAccessToken()}
        />
```

Comment: for route its HOC, if  loggedin then show component else login screen. will that work I want authentication for component must not be accessed without login

Comment: Updated my answer, if you required authentication (here I have considered token based authentication) you can used `AuthRoute`

Comment: please check the updated code in saga.js is that the way we write  . the other thing is i dont have access token authroute is build in library ?I'm confused {Yourcomponent} can be "app" or app must have different route?

Comment: Yes you have written right code, it can be a seperate action and calling that action would be fine. It is okay if you don't have access token you can remove that part or can add yours mechanism to validate user is logged in or not and check that instead of hasAccessToken()

Comment: Please check I've updated the code the saga as well the index

Comment: I dont think redirect in props required anymore

Comment: can you please update your code. AuthRoute is requireAuth right?

Comment: What I need to update?? AuthRoute is type of Route from `react-router-auth` package it is not a function/method it is type of route which will help you to automatically rediret to login if the user is invalidate/session expires/ anything else happens

Comment: FYI- react-router-redux has been deprecated.  They suggest using connected-react-router.  Code is the same as above.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Answer (score 8):

I am going to tell you the best and the **simplest way** from which you can redirect in any part of the application(i.e. inside redux and outside as well).

**Step: 1**
Create *history.js* file.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Step : 2** *Import* it inside *App.js* file (or, where you have made routers of your application).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';
import history from './history';

const App = () => {
    return (<Router history={history}>
        <div className='App'>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={ROUTES.NOTIFICATIONS} component={Notification} />
                <Route exacr path={ROUTES.USER_PROFILE} component={UserProfile} />
                <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
                <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
                <Route path='*' component={SignInPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Step: 3** Inside Saga file just import the history.

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Auth } from "../service/api/Auth";
import history from '../containers/App/history';
import * as ACTION from '../constants/ActionType';
import { put, takeLatest, call } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { userLoginSuccess, userLoginFailed } from "../actions/auth";

export function* userLogin(loginData) {

  const payLoad = loginData.payload;
  try {
    const loginUserData = yield call(Auth.userLoginApiCall, payLoad);
    yield put(userLoginSuccess(TOKEN));
    history.push('/posts'); //  Redirect to Post Page
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(push(userLoginFailed()))
  }
}

export default function* userLoginRequest() {

  yield takeLatest(ACTION.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, userLogin);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I used to wait for the result of the saga using `useEffect` inside of the component, which was quite tedious.